# Django model accepting a generic key pair entry

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am designing a web api using Django Rest Framework. The API requirement is that end user can send an arbitrary key pair value (can be more than 1 pair at the same time) and I need to store them in the database.

That list of key pair currently has around 200 items and it may grow in the future.

Is there a way I can represent a "generic" model in Django so that I can store those key pair value?

Currently I have such models:

```
class MyConfig(models.Model):
    pass

class ConfigItem(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    config = models.ForeignKey(MyConfig, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Whereas MyConfig will be the API endpoint (using django rest framework) but I am not sure how to pass a list of key/pair value to the same endpoint and then create the ConfigItem one by one.

Comment: Create nested serializer of ConfigItem in Myconfig. Override the create serializer of MyConfig and save the nested data.

Comment: If  you need key,value data for many models (not only MyConfig), then use generic relations.  You  may need to write a decorator that decorates create/update function  of the main serializer( of Myconfig, etc). to achieve DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you schema is has one to many relationship.
For such case create another table for 'many' relationship and also for API view make another serializer of newly added class.

Ex.

```
class One(Models.model):
fields = model.fields(validations)

class Many(Models.model)
    fields = model.fields(validations)
    parent_obj = model.ForeignKey(One, validations, related_name="Child_Many_class_obj")
```

In serializers.py file

```
class ManySerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):  
    fields
    Logic
    etc

class OneSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    Child_Many_class_obj = ManySerializer(read/write_only=True, Many=True, etc..)
    other fields
```

Comment: for further reference you can visit https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/